# How to Try Catch in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Situation:

```
//trollCommand.php
[...]
foreach ($trolltypes as $type) { //$type=={"Frost","RandomBroken","Forest"}
    try {
        $output->writeln($type);
        $troll={"get".$type."TrollType"}();
        $output->writeln("TEST 1");
        $troll->__load();
        $output->writeln("TEST 2");
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException $e) {
        $output->writeln("WARNING: TROLL ENTITY DOES NOT EXIST.");
        continue;
    }
    $output->writeln("TROLLING");
    do_something_with_troll($troll);
}
```

getFrostTrollType loads ok, getForestTrollType should be loaded ok too, but before that, it is a problem, getRandomBrokenTrollType() deliberately does not exist, and then I see message in console:

```
 Frost
 Test 1
 Test 2
 TROLLING
 RandomBroken
 Test 1
 [Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException]  
 Entity was not found. 
 //[EXIT FROM SCRIPT]
 troll@troll-machine ~/trollSandbox/ $ _
```

it should be: WARNING: TROLL ENTITY DOES NOT EXIST. and then continue; but it does not happen

How to check existing of a object's method?

Comment: What doesn't happen? The warning or the continue? Or neither?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the Exception thrown by Doctrine is called `Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException` and you are catching `EntityNotFoundException`.

Thats a difference, the namespace matters.

to debug this, catch `Exception` instead and observe the type of the actual exception. then replace it.

Comment: I did that, and then I discovered, that I am stupid. I made copy of the try catch block from other script to make a little edit only in new script, but I forgot to add line "use ... ;"...

Answer (score 35):

if you're trying to catch any exception, you should use a backslash before "Exception".

E.g.:

```
try{
    //do stuff here
}
catch(\Exception $e){
    error_log($e->getMessage());
}
```

If you don't use a backslash, the exception won't be caught. This is due to how namespaces are used in PHP / Symfony.

Comment: This! Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Exception Type is - **\Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException** 
Don`t forget starting "\"
Example -

```
 try {
        $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();
        $entityManager->remove($entity);
        $entityManager->flush(); // save to the database
    } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException $ex) {
        echo "Exception Found - " . $ex->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    }
```