# if Security denies access for a Certain Role , Trigger a Jquery Function in Symfony3

Tags: jquery, symfony, symfony-3.3

I have a certain notification popup I want to trigger if the Security denies access for `ROLE_USER` to use the path `Admin_Only` , I successfully configured this , which works perfectly, on my :

> security.yml

```
 access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/Admin_Only, role: ROLE_ADMIN }

access_denied_url: /home
```

and I have a JQuery Function on my Twig file to which I am rendering my `/home` Action let's call it `accessDeniedJQ`.
The question is How do I check and where ( Action in the Controller or on twig ) that a redirection has happened and the access was denied , in other words how do I check if this exception was raised so the JQ function starts.

Comment: have you tried `console.log()` at the different points of the application? In php, I believe you can do a `<?php echo "<script>console.log('')</script>" ?>` as your die.

Comment: In native php i know it's possible but using the twig templating i lack the syntax to catch the exception , a code example would help alot

Comment: Can't you change the url to /home?redirected=true and directly look for that in your jQuery?

Comment: @KhaledOuertani how about  `try catch`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23731604/how-to-try-catch-in-symfony

Comment: @Salketer Thanks alot , I did pass some parameters along with the path , I checked for them on the twig and depending on its existance I was able to trigger the function , please elaborate more with some code example so this question has a right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your framework does an internal redirect (or you just can't know if there was an HTTP redirect) your best bet is to use an URL with a query string to let your code be aware of it.

Here my suggestion is to append something similar to `redirected=true` in the url so it would become `/home?redirected=true`

Using the function taken from the answer at [jquery get querystring from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656843/jquery-get-querystring-from-url)

```
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

I can easily detect that my page was redirected and act accordingly:

```
if(getUrlVars().redirected){
    alert('You are not allowed there, got redirected!');
}
```